# Stroke practice

Tags: characters

Is there a sentence in Mandarin either traditional or modern that uses all the strokes. Similar to " The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" used to teach typing

Comment: How to define "all strokes"? They are basically only five (kinds of) strokes in Chinese, 横 竖 撇 点（捺） 折, which all exist in "你好".

Comment: there seems to exist a story about a famous 书法家 helping his son (or some young relative at any rate) to practice 书法, the gist of the story being that the character 永 contains all 6 basic strokes

Comment: cf.    https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%B0%B8%E5%AD%97%E5%85%AB%E6%B3%95/959004  相传，东晋大书法家王羲之用几年的时间，专门写“永”字。

Comment: @fefe I'm pretty sure it's categorized in 8 strife types traditionally. 永字八筆

Answer (score 1):

traditionally, people used the character 永 (u+6c38) for practicing chinese calligraphy, by brush pen; in which, it's called 永字八法, that, all **eight (8)** strokes were used in this character.

[image]

well, a hard nib of pencil, ball pen, or fountain pen; cannot show the beauty of "softness" of a brush.

btw, the internet archive has a book named "書法正傳", the volume 3 is talk about "永字八法":

https://archive.org/stream/06067106.cn#page/n106/mode/2up

edited, info added.

well, there's another book "御定佩文齋書畫譜", again volume 3, in the internet archive talked about "永字八法":

https://archive.org/stream/06067076.cn#page/n30/mode/2up

[image]

i would believe the first verse, that's

> 禁經云八法起於隸字之始

other claimings are, imo, **fake** info.

have fun :)

Comment: see above comments #2,3 (it seems the story referred to in comment #2 in fact is about 王羲之)

Comment: frankly, i'm stunned to read that there're only 5, or 6 types of strokes in chinese. my immediate "association" of it, is "this culture is dead, in some area".

Comment: ＂教学汉字规范手册＂：＂汉字的基本笔画有横、竖、撇、点、折，５种（some authorities list a 6th, 提, otherwise included in 点 as long 点）。有以上基本笔画变形扩展形成的笔画共有２６种", these 26 have been mentioned and listed at this site before (lists readily available on web)

Answer (score -1):

To **practice** strokes, buy some 書法字帖 (copybook for calligraphy) or 書法練習簿 (Calligraphy practice book)

Write the characters stoke by stoke with 毛筆 (writing brush).

This way, you can practice all the stokes and acquire good penmanship in Chinese too.

書法練習簿:

[image: 書法練習簿]

毛筆:

[image: 毛筆]

書法字帖:

[image: 書法字帖]

Answer (score -2):

> 我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体

Project homepage: http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/utf8/index.html